# Flask access request data when uploading file with angular

Tags: python, angularjs, file-upload, request

I'm uploading a file using `angular` and try to access the uploaded file in `flask`. 
This is no problem and works fine. However, when I add more request parameters I cannot seem to find them in the `flask` `request` object.

For example, uploading a file using `ngFileUpload` (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) I can specify more meta-information like this:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/upload',
        data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
    })
};
```

where `username` is extra meta-information.

Here's the flask code (using Flask-Restful):

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask.ext.restful import Api, Resource

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'csv'}
def allowed_file(fn):
    return '.' in fn and fn.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Upload(Resource):
    def post():
        file = request.files['file']
        fn = file.filename
        if file and allowed_file(fn):
            try:
                # code for saving file
                return Response(status=200)
            except:
                return Response(status=500)
        return Response(status=500)

api.add_resource(Upload, '/api/upload')
```

In flask I can access the `file` through `request.files['file']`, but the `username` information/variable is nowhere to be found.

Is this not possible in flask, am I missing something, or what's going on here?

Comment: Could you share your flask code as well? It is definitely possible to access url parameters in flask but to help you we need to see the route code.

Comment: @ciacicode The flask code is quite trivial, but I added it as requested.

Comment: Has anybody found the solution to this?  I'm running into the same issue as Tim.  I have CORS added in my flask app, but can't seem to find `username` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think @ciacicode was right to ask you about your python code.

You are probably running into a [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) violation with Angular calling Python.

1. Add an import

See Flask-CORS: http://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/index.html

`from flask.ext.cors import CORS`

2. Add CORS to your app

Simple addition to your code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
api = Api(app)
```

Adding `CORS` made your code sample run for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the CORS is not doing anything for you, then use `request.values['username']`